# My Computer keeps crashing even when using another distro

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, crash

My main Linux computer crashes frequently (when in sleep mode, for ubuntu) I don't know why!

I don't think this is the kernel crashing because it responds correctly to the `Magic SysRq` ( <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> ) and does reboot as expected.

Almost every time, when I finished working, I let it go into sleep mode (or let the screen lock itself), but sometimes, when I power it on again, nothing shows up or a random color shows up and I have to use that `Magic SysRq` thing to get it working again.

I'm really tired of this.

Here are my specs :

> Screen : 3440x1440 @ 165Hz (I don't know if it's gonna help)

> CPU : Intel CORE i7 3770K @ 3.5GHz

> GPU : AMD Radeon RX 550 4GB

> RAM : 8GB DDR3

> OS  : (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) Now, I use Arch Linux

> WM : (awesomewm) Arch + dwm

However, in my Late 2006 Linux MacBook which is less powerful, I **never** got that problem.

I hope I get this fixed soon :).

##### EDIT : I now installed Artix/Arch (without SystemD, there is runit instead) and still got that same problem.

Comment: That's not a lot of information to go on. Perhaps a little more research is appropriate. Did you try a different OS?

Comment: The "nothing or random color shows up" indicates the problem could be in saving & restoring the display state in sleep mode. To confirm this, you could set up your computer to be connectable by SSH, then see if you can access it with SSH when the problem occurs. If you can get a SSH connection when the display is blank or random, you'll know that the problem is limited to display only. In that case, the sleep mode could be configured to unload the display drivers on sleeping & reloading them on wake-up - but that workaround would make sleeping equivalent to logging out.

Comment: I forgot to say that the NUM LOCK thing in the keyboard stays on and doesn't turn off

Comment: @Shogun8 No, but I suspect CKB-NEXT (my RGB Keyboard driver) to be the culprit because sometimes, when the keyboard is plugged in sleep mode, It just turns on randomly and crashes. But when unplugged, I get these crashes less frequently.

Comment: @telcoM I'll try this! :)

Comment: @Shōgun8 yep, I THINK CKB-Next IS the problem, i'm using Ckb-Next v0.4.2 and the latest release (v0.4.4) has this bugfix : "Fixed various deadlocks when resuming from suspend or during device initialisation" https://github.com/ckb-next/ckb-next/releases/tag/v0.4.4

Comment: That CKB-Next certainly sounds like it might be the culprit too. Likewise, you might be able to customize the sleep/wake processes to include unloading that driver before sleep and reloading it when waking up. Unfortunately I'm not quite up to date on the recommended procedure on current Ubuntu, but things like this have been possible for quite a while, so I'm pretty sure there is still a way to do it. Hope the fix in the newest version works, but the unload/reload might be your Plan B.

Comment: @telcoM Upgrading to the latest ckb-next didn't help, i'll try your solution then ...

Comment: @telcoM How am I supposed to do that ? Please !

Answer (score 0):

At least on Debian 10 (and probably also on Ubuntu), there are scripts in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` directory that will get executed with parameter `pre` when going to sleep and with `post` when waking up.

That suggests you could create `/etc/systemd/system-sleep/` directory for your own customizations and drop your own scripts there.

Your script might look like this, for example:

Filename: `/etc/systemd/system-sleep/workaround-script`

Contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

case "$1" in
        pre)    systemctl stop ckb-next-daemon.service
                # add here any other commands if needed to fully unload the CKB-Next driver
                exit 0
                ;;
        post)   systemctl start ckb-next-daemon.service
                exit 0
                ;;
        *)      exit 1
                ;;
esac
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(